# react-select custom single label for multi values?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

When selecting an option in `react-select` multi select, the default behavior is that it adds the option from dropdown to the input and the selected option disappears from the menu.

How do I prevent the selected options from disappearing and how do I replace the default selected option elements in the controller to a single text element saying "n selected".

My react select currently:

```
<ReactSelect
  isMulti
  options={vSystems}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
  getOptionValue={(option) => option.id}
  defaultValue={vSystems}
  onChange={(val) => setSelectedSystems(val)}
  className="my-react-select-container"
  classNamePrefix="my-react-select"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to still be an open question, figured I'd share.

From what I could find, there is no built-in functionality for this. However, this can be achieved with several actions:

1. To prevent selected options from disappearing, use `hideSelectedOptions` parameter, is should be false.
2. To replace the element, you need to pass a custom one into `components` prop. However, there is no element for selected options wrapper; there is one for each selected option and one for the whole element. Replacing the latter would be more accurate, however it will remove also several eventListeners, so I ended up replacing the former, MultiValueContainer, and making it show only once.

Something like this (not tested properly):
the select itself:

```
<Select
    classNamePrefix="qvDropdown"
    isMulti
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    options={myOptions}
    defaultValue={myDefaultValue}
    onChange={v => { console.log('selected', v) }}
    components={{
        Option: MultSelectorOption,
        ClearIndicator: null,
        MultiValueContainer: MultSelectorValue
    }}
    hideSelectedOptions={false}
    placeholder={t("all")}
    fullPlaceholder={t("xSelected")}
/>
```

and the custom component:

```
export const MultSelectorValue = ({ selectProps, data }) => {
    const getVal = selectProps.getOptionValue;
    const selected = selectProps.value;
    const isFirst = getVal(data) == getVal(selected[0]);

    if(!isFirst)
        return null;

    const str = selected.length == selectProps.options.length ? selectProps.placeholder : (selected.length + " " + selectProps.fullPlaceholder);

    return (<div>{str}</div>);
}
```